# How to get element by ID in IE? (Visual Studio 8?)

Tags: javascript, dom, internet-explorer

Using document.GetElementById(thingieID) doesn't seem to work. 
Can anyone help this DOM newbie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do with the element, or what the problem is.

Here's an example of using document.GetElementById() in a webpage, in a function that is invoked on the onClick event for a button.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example of GetElementById</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="hello">Hello World</p>
    <input type="button" value="Update" onclick="btn1_Click();"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // <![CDATA[
      function btn1_Click()
      {
          if (document.getElementById('hello')) {
              document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML = 'Hello World - this was inserted using JavaScript at ' + new Date().toString();
          }
      }
    // ]]>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can see this run at:
http://jsbin.com/afaga/2

Comment: thanks for answer - at the risk of exposing my ignorance, what i really need is a handle to the object within Javascript - assumed this was the XPATH, but maybe not

here's an example: this "node" or element or whatever is within a table/tbody/tr:

<th align="left" id="GridHeaderCol4" style="padding-bottom: 2px; padding-left: 2px; width: 70px; padding-right: 2px; cursor: hand; padding-top: 2px;" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundImage='url....>

using document.GetElementById('GridHeaderCol4') doesn't work - no object

so using IE only (not Firefox), i need to get a handle to the object

Comment: it's not XPath.  An Element ID is not xpath. Maybe you could reframe your question, provide a very simple .htm document that shows the problem you're having.

Comment: The problem is just in capitalization?

Comment: Working, capitalization may have been the problem.  IE8 Dev Tools (F12) using Find=>Select By Click is useful, then View=>Source=>DOM Element, and construct the Element ID from the XML tree.  Thanks for everyone's input.  This site comes up a lot in my Google searches, and it seems like a useful resource :-)